# Python - Pymongo Insert and Update Documents

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Using PyMongo, I have a set of dict's in a list that I'd like to submit to my MongoDB. Some of the items in the list are new entries, and some are to update.

Example:

**On Server Database:**

```
[{"_id" : 1, "foo" : "bar}]
```

**To send to database:**

```
[{"_id" : 1, "foo" : "HELLO"}, {"_id" : 2, "Blah" : "Bloh"}]
```

I'm currently using the following to insert documents, but how would I do something like stated above? Any help is appreciated!

```
collection.insert(myDict)
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use [`upsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-upsert) option:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
cl = MongoClient()
coll = cl["local"]["test2"]

data = [{"_id" : 1, "foo" : "HELLO"}, {"_id" : 2, "Blah" : "Bloh"}]
for d in data:
    coll.update({'_id':d['_id']}, d, True)
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this with a single API call ? Something like a "bulk" update, for better perfomances.

Comment: @John Did you figure out a way to do this in bulk? something similar to insert_many

Comment: How could I obtain the `object_id` of each inserted object?   @Roman Pekar

Comment: bulk update here: https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html

Comment: DeprecationWarning: update is deprecated. Use replace_one, update_one or update_many instead. [Pymongo 3.12.0]

Answer (score 8):

You can also use [save](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.save)

```
import pymongo
con = pymongo.MongoClient()
coll = con.db_name.collection_name

docs = [{"_id" : 1, "foo" : "HELLO"}, {"_id" : 2, "Blah" : "Bloh"}]

for doc in docs:
    coll.save(doc)
```

Comment: _From Docs:_ **DEPRECATED** - Use [`insert_one()`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_one) or [`replace_one()`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.replace_one) instead.

Answer (score 8):

You have to use the `upsert` to update (or insert) your data

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
collection = client.my_database.my_collection

objects = [{"_id" : 1, "foo" : "HELLO"}, {"_id" : 2, "Blah" : "Bloh"}]
for obj in objects:
     collection.replace_one({"_id": obj["_id"]}, obj, upsert=True)
```

Use `replace_one` as the `update` method [is deprecated](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update):

https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.replace_one

If you want to use bulk update:

```py
from pymongo import ReplaceOne

update_objects = list()
for obj in objects:
    update_objects.append(ReplaceOne( {'_id': obj['_id']},  obj, upsert=True))

collection.bulk_write(update_objects)
```

Answer (score 5):

For pymongo 3.0 and later:

```
import pymongo
con = pymongo.MongoClient()
collection = con.db_name.collection_name

docs = [{"_id" : 1, "foo" : "HELLO"}, {"_id" : 2, "Blah" : "Bloh"}]
for d in docs:
    collection.update_many({'_id':d['_id']}, d,True)
```

Ref: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html